# Using Puppeteer with Electron throws 'Could not find browser revision' error. Runs fine with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer

I've tried with Puppeteer v5.4.0, v5.4.1, and v5.5.0, Windows 10/MacOS, and Node v12/v14.0.1/v15.0.3 to try to get Puppeteer to run in Electron.

Doing a simple `puppeteer.launch()` like this in the main process of a React application:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async function(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
})();
```

returns this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not find browser revision 818858. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (Launcher.js:120)
    at async http:/localhost:8080/main.js:61295
```

I've tried running `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install`, setting the `executablePath` in the `launch()` method, deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, but none of these solutions seem to work. In the case of setting a path, it returns a `ENOENT` error. Weird enough, though, writing a small script and running it through `node test.js` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours of tinkering, here's how I figured it out:

Instead of calling from the main process, set the function in the renderer process and call it, like this:

```js
/* main.js - Renderer Process */
ipcMain.on('spawn-browser', (event, arg) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    // Your other functions...
});
```

And from the main process, you can call something like:

```js
require('electron').ipcRenderer.send('spawn-browser', args);
```

which works.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/53997175.html), try one of the following:

```
sudo npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Or:

for linux:

1- you must have installed chromium browser using this command :

$sudo apt install -y chromium-browser

2- you have to get the excutable path of chromium using this command :

$which chromium-browser

3-put the executable path as an argument to the launch function :

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
   (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
   headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
    })();
```